# Hydrostatic pressure in varying cross-section reservoir

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

Consider an axisymmetric reservoir whose axis of symmetry is $z$. Let its cross section $A(z)$ become progressively thinner as $z$ increases. That is, $A(z) \xrightarrow{}0$ as $z \xrightarrow{}\infty$

Now I want to calculate the pressure at $z_0$ for different heights of liquid columns $z_c$ ($z_c>z_0$). The hydrostatic gauge pressure is obtained as $p=\rho g (z_{c}-z_{0})$.

The above expression implies that $p$ depends only on $z_c$. But as $A$ gets thinner, we are effectively adding less and less "mass" for each extra centimeter of $z_c$. So I want to understand if, physically, there is a certain limit where $p$ stops following this expression, and if yes, is there another expression for $p$?

I have found similar questions but it's still not clear to me.

Comment: Just some thoughts. Pressure = force/area = mg/A. So you can see as A gets smaller, the ratio of the force due to the lesser mass in that region to the area remains constant. At some point, as the reservoir (tube) gets thinner, capillary force between the tube wall and fluid will become significant. If the fluid column is tall enough, the static pressure and in turn density of the fluid at the bottom of column will become so great so as to form a black hole.

Comment: @Armadillo, thanks. So if I understood well, the expression $p=\rho g h$ holds even when the capillary effect becomes significant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without considering capillary action, the change in pressure $\Delta p$ within the fluid under consideration due to a change in fluid column height $\Delta h$ is (assuming constant $\rho$ and constant $g$)

$$\Delta p = p_a + \rho g \Delta h,$$

where $p_a$ is the "atmospheric" pressure imparted on the top surface of the fluid column. Taking capillary forces into consideration, the pressure change is
$$\Delta p = p_a - 2\sigma \cos \theta /r + \rho g \Delta h,$$

where $2\sigma \cos \theta /r$ is the [Laplace equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%E2%80%93Laplace_equation#Capillary_pressure_in_a_tube) for capillary pressure.